# Можно ли дождаться выполнения всех запросов на странице с помощью Guzzle?

Tags: php, laravel, http, parse, guzzle

Всем привет!

У меня Laravel приложение, для запросов используется GuzzleClient.

Я делаю запрос на сторонний урл

```
https://russian.alibaba.com/trade/search?IndexArea=product_en&tab=all&SearchText=abc
```

Чтобы разобрать DOM дерево с продуктами, но продукты отображаются из других запросов, которые сложно обнаружить в Network DevTools.
Список продуктов хранится в id="root", но там пока нет нод.

Могу ли я как то дождаться выполнения всех js запросов, чтобы DOM дерево донаполнилось?

Знаю, что как то так можно сделать на Selenium

Comment: Очевидно, нельзя. но никто не мешает вам самому сходить в эти доп запрос и взят там данные напрямую